# Magento v2 REST API - use_config_manage_stock setter does not exist

Tags: magento2

```
 \"UseConfigManageStock\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Catalog\\Api\\Data\\ProductInterface
```

I have sync between my backonffice applicaiton and Magento v2. this was working fine but all of a suddned it started gving above error.

I would appreciate for Any help?